# Dot notation to Json in python

Tags: python, json

I receive data from the Loggly service in dot notation, but to put data back in, it must be in JSON.

Hence, I need to convert:

```
{'json.message.status.time':50, 'json.message.code.response':80, 'json.time':100}
```

Into:

```
{'message': {'code': {'response': 80}, 'status': {'time': 50}}, 'time': 100}
```

I have put together a function to do so, but I wonder if there is a more direct and simpler way to accomplish the same result.

```
def dot_to_json(a):

    # Create root for JSON tree structure
    resp = {}

    for k,v in a.items():
        # eliminate json. (if metric comes from another type, it will keep its root)
        k = re.sub(r'\bjson.\b','',k)
        if '.' in k:
            # Field has a dot
            r = resp
            s = ''
            k2 =  k.split('.')
            l = len(k2)
            count = 0
            t = {}
            for f in k2:
                count += 1
                if f not in resp.keys():
                    r[f]={}
                r = r[f]
                if count < l:
                    s += "['" + f + "']"
                else:
                    s = "resp%s" % s
                    t = eval(s)
                    # Assign value to the last branch
                    t[f] = v
        else:
            r2 = resp
            if k not in resp.keys():
                r2[k] = {}
            r2[k] = v
    return resp
```

Comment: What is that business with eval-ing `"resp%s"`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can turn the path into dictionary access with:

```
def dot_to_json(a):
    output = {}
    for key, value in a.iteritems():
        path = key.split('.')
        if path[0] == 'json':
            path = path[1:]
        target = reduce(lambda d, k: d.setdefault(k, {}), path[:-1], output)
        target[path[-1]] = value
    return output
```

This takes the key as a path, ignoring the first `json` part. With [`reduce()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reduce) you can walk the elements of `path` (except for the last one) and fetch the nested dictionary with it.

Essentially you start at `output` and for each element in `path` fetch the value and use that value as the input for the next iteration. Here [`dict.setdefault()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault) is used to default to a new empty dictionary each time a key doesn't yet exist. For a path `['foo', 'bar', 'baz']` this comes down to the call `output.setdefault('foo', {}).setdefault('bar', {}).setdefault('baz', {})`, only more compact and supporting arbitrary length paths.

The innermost dictionary is then used to set the value with the last element of the path as the key.

Demo:

```
>>> def dot_to_json(a):
...     output = {}
...     for key, value in a.iteritems():
...         path = key.split('.')[1:]  # ignore the json. prefix
...         target = reduce(lambda d, k: d.setdefault(k, {}), path[:-1], output)
...         target[path[-1]] = value
...     return output
... 
>>> dot_to_json({'json.message.status.time':50, 'json.message.code.response':80, 'json.time':100}))
{'message': {'status': {'time': 50}, 'code': {'response': 80}}, 'time': 100}
```

Comment: It appears he only wants to ignore the prefix if it is "json", while leaving it if the key begins with something other than "json".

Comment: I am trying to understand how your answer works. From page 577 in "Learning Python" by O'Reilly, I gather that the reduce function can be expressed in equivalent terms as:                               def myreduce(function, sequence):
    tally = sequence[0]
    for next in sequence[1:]:
        tally = function(tally, next)
    return tally                                                           However, when applied to the solution above, I get "myreduce() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)". Is there an equivalent expression to the reduce function you have invoqued?

Comment: @user3394978: I added a start value (the `output` value); if present it is used instead of `sequence[0]` for `tally`, and the loop is over `for next in sequence:` instead of skipping the first value.

Comment: @user3394978: the [documentation or `reduce()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reduce) gives a better equivalent.

Comment: I see from the comment in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19589233/reduce-function-with-three-parameters/25393471#25393471 that it indeed has 3 parameters, with the 3rd being the optional initializer.