# How to indicate function's Parameter value (x and y value from range in reduce function) from a reduce function in Python?

Tags: python, reduce

## This is my Function

```
def add(x, y):
    return x+y
```

## This is reduce Function

```
reduce(add, range(1, 11))
```

Comment: [Reduce function with three parameters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19589233/reduce-function-with-three-parameters)

Answer (score 0):

On the first *iteration*, reduce takes the first two values in sequence and they are fed to the function as the first and second positional arguments. The function's return value then becomes the first positional argument for the next *iteration* and the second positional argument is the next item in the sequence.  The only control you have is how you use the values in your function.

```
>>> def f(a,b):
    return a-b

>>> def g(a,b):
    return b-a

>>> reduce(f, range(5))
-10
>>> reduce(g, range(5))
2
>>>
```

If you are using builtins, you have no control.