# Python reduce & Lambda with multiple params

Tags: python-3.x, lambda, reduce

Is There any way by which I could use 3 variables in reduce(lambda f) combination like

```
reduce(lambda a, b, c : a*b+c, <list_for_a&b>, <range_for_c>)
```

I can use map() function. But thought of knowing a new possibility, if any.

Comment: You can refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19589233/reduce-function-with-three-parameters#19589254.

Comment: from the docs: "Apply function of two arguments cumulatively to the items of sequence, from left to right, so as to reduce the sequence to a single value".    It seems what you are trying to do here is create a new list of two existing lists. That's not what `reduce` is for. Try `list comprehensions`.

Comment: Could you post example values for "list_for_a&b" and "range_for_c" and the expected output for those values ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can zip the two sequences and them work on the result.

```
values_for_a_and_b = ... # I assume this is a list of tuples
values_for_c       = ... #
product = zip(values_for_a_and_b, values_for_c)    # This gives a list like [((a, b), c)]
```

Now it looks like you're trying to do a map, rather than a reduce.
You can use the product as follows:

```
map(lambda x: x[0][0] * x[0][1] + x[1], product)
```

But since Python doesn't have pattern matching, it's not really elegant.