# How to count num letter appears in the word with reduce?

Tags: python-3.x, reduce

I'm trying to understand how is the next example is really work.
this function is basically will count the number of times the letter appears in the word, but unfortunately it is a bit incomprehensible to me. I would love to get some good explanation for this.

```
def count_appearances1(letter, word):

    func = lambda counter,l: counter + 1 if l == letter else counter

    return reduce(func, word,0)
```

Comment: Feast your eyes on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_(higher-order_function)

Answer (score 0):

*The reduce(fun,seq) function is used to apply a particular function passed in its argument to all of the list elements mentioned in the sequence passed along.*

At first step,the first element of the sequence (word) is compared with the letter, if they are same only then counter is increased.
This step is repeated until the sequence ends.

you can also see answer to this question [click](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19589233/12324247)

Hope this was helpful..

Comment: thank you for your answer it was helpfull. only one thing i didnt understand yet is what about the third parameter in reduce? here I pass in  - 0 and it connected immediaitely to the counter, but why is that? how I'll know next time to connect between the third parameter to the first argument?

Comment: About the third parameter, it is optional and its value is by default placed even before iterable. some examples ->  (https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/functions/reduce.html#example-2)