# Which is the pythonic way to 'reduce' a list applying a three-parameter function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, functional-programming

I am used to the FP/haskell-like concept of reduce, already implemented as a built-in library in Python:

```
from functools import reduce
lst = [1,2,3,4,5]
reduce(lambda x, y: x*y, lst)
# result: 120
```

However this doesn't work for, e.g., a lambda with three arguments:

```
from functools import reduce
lst = [1,2,3,4,5]
reduce(lambda x, y, z: x*y+z, lst)
# expected result: (1*2+3) * 4 + 5
# actual result: 
#   TypeError: <lambda>() missing 1 required positional argument: 'z'
```

The rationale is to keep the rule "the previous result is the next first argument".

**Is there a built-in implementation, or clever/simple combination of functional constructs to achieve such goal?**

---

ps. Beware of [pseudo-duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19589233/reduce-function-with-three-parameters)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A reasonably simple implementation would be

```
import inspect


def nreduce(fn, lst):
    nargs = len(inspect.signature(fn).parameters)
    args = list(lst)
    while len(args) >= nargs:
        next_args = [args.pop(0) for x in range(nargs)]
        args.insert(0, fn(*next_args))
    return args


lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
print(nreduce(lambda x, y, z: x * y + z, lst))
```

If you want to be fancy, you can use a `deque` to make the insertion of the just-reduced value to the left of the list faster:

```
import collections

def nreduce(fn, lst):
    nargs = len(inspect.signature(fn).parameters)
    arg_queue = collections.deque(lst)
    while len(arg_queue) >= nargs:
        next_args = [arg_queue.popleft() for x in range(nargs)]
        arg_queue.appendleft(fn(*next_args))
    return list(arg_queue)
```

If the length of `lst` isn't divisible by the arity of `fn`, the remaining elements will be returned too.

Yet another implementation which works with any iterable without copying into other lists or queues (which *won't* return the rest of the `lst`, just the values it consumed out of it):

```
def nreduce(fn, lst):
    nargs = len(inspect.signature(fn).parameters)
    lst_iter = iter(lst)
    next_args = []
    while True:
        try:
            while len(next_args) < nargs:
                next_args.append(next(lst_iter))
        except StopIteration:
            break
        next_args = [fn(*next_args)]
    return next_args
```